Rolling sum with partial value for last day
I can't figure out how to write a query that returns rolling sum by item based on rules in another table.
Below is a table that list in chronological order the stock value of an item on specific days.
Table 1: Stock



item
stock
date




Blade
10
1/3/2020


Blade
20
1/4/2020


Blade
30
1/5/2020


Blade
40
1/6/2020


Blade
50
1/7/2020


Blade
60
1/8/2020


Blade
70
1/9/2020


Table
10
1/3/2020


Table
20
1/4/2020


Table
30
1/5/2020


Table
40
1/6/2020


Table
50
1/7/2020


Table
60
1/8/2020


Table
70
1/9/2020



Another table has two rules for each item on how many days are used to calcaute the rolling sum values.
Table 2: Rule



item
rule
value




Blade
cum_sum
2.5


Blade
lead_sum
2.5


Table
cum_sum
3


Table
lead_sum
3








Output:
cum_sum: For Balde, date - 1/3/2020, rule is 2.5 and so the value = 10+20+30 * 0.5
lead_sum: For Balde, date - 1/3/2020, rule is 2.5 and so the value = 20+30+40 * 0.5
How do I write the query to consider partial values for the last date.



item
stock
date
cum_sum
lead_sum




Blade
10
1/3/2020
45
70


Blade
20
1/4/2020
70
95


Blade
30
1/5/2020
95
120


Blade
40
1/6/2020
120
145


Blade
50
1/7/2020
145
130


Blade
60
1/8/2020
130
70


Blade
70
1/9/2020
70
0
















Table
10
1/3/2020
60
90


Table
20
1/4/2020
90
120


Table
30
1/5/2020
120
150


Table
40
1/6/2020
150
180


Table
50
1/7/2020
180
130


Table
60
1/8/2020
130
70


Table
70
1/9/2020
70
0



https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=c87e6a47-0949-4781-b8b5-3559929a063d

Please consider following these suggestions.

A window function with a custom frame comes to mind, like:
... sum(stock) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND _offset FOLLOWING)

But there are two issues:

_offset in the frame clause does not allow variables.

_offset in the frame clause does not process fractional numbers.
If you pass a numeric type with fractional  part, it's rounded in the cast to integer. This is particularly problematic with floating point types like double precision, where 2.5 can round to 2 (!) due to inexact storage of the value. (I would not involve floating point types in these kinds of calculation to begin with!)


The manual:

In the offset PRECEDING and offset FOLLOWING frame
options, the offset must be an expression not containing any
variables, aggregate functions, or window functions. The meaning of
the offset depends on the frame mode:

In ROWS mode, the offset must yield a non-null, non-negative integer, and the option means that the frame starts or
ends the specified number of rows before or after the current row.


To work around issue 1, loop over items and execute dynamic SQL in PL/pgSQL.
To work around issue 2, truncate the upper bound, and add another value with lead() multiplied by the remainder:
Assuming referential integrity, and all columns not NOT NULL and values in the allowed range. Else you need to do more.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_rolling_sum(_items text[] = null)
  RETURNS TABLE (
   item     text
 , stock    numeric
 , date     date
 , cum_sum  numeric
 , lead_sum numeric
   )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _rule record;
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   FOR _rule IN
      SELECT r.item
           , any_value(r.value) FILTER (WHERE r.rule = 'cum_sum') AS cum_value
           , any_value(r.value) FILTER (WHERE r.rule = 'lead_sum') AS lead_value
      FROM   rule r
      WHERE (_items IS NULL OR r.item = ANY(_items))
      GROUP  BY r.item
      ORDER  BY r.item  -- ? suppose that's the desired order?
   LOOP
      _sql := format(
         $q$
         SELECT s.item, s.stock, s.date
              , round (         sum(s.stock) OVER (ORDER BY s.date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND %1$s FOLLOWING)
                     + lead(s.stock, %1$s + 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY s.date) * $1
                     , 2)  -- AS cum_sum
              , round (COALESCE(sum(s.stock) OVER (ORDER BY s.date ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND %2$s FOLLOWING), 0)
                     + lead(s.stock, %2$s + 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY s.date) * $2 
                     , 2)  -- AS lead_sum
         FROM   stock s
         WHERE  s.item = %3$L
         $q$
       , trunc(_rule.cum_value) - 1
       , trunc(_rule.lead_value)
       , _rule.item
       );

--    RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;    -- debug?
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _sql  -- execute
      USING _rule.cum_value::numeric % 1
          , _rule.lead_value::numeric % 1;  --  % 1 gets fractional remainder
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;

fiddle
Call for all items:
SELECT * FROM my_rolling_sum();  -- no argument

Call for given items:
SELECT * FROM my_rolling_sum('{Blade}');

Be sure to have an index on stock(item) to make this fast. Ideally on stock(item, date) INCLUDE (stock), but that may be to specialized.
The aggregate function any_value() was added with Postgres 16. Substitute with min() in older versions. (And remember to declare your version of Postgres in all questions.)
Produces your result.
There are subtleties with rounding, null-handling, sort order and display, which the question didn't clarify.

Thanks for the interesting solution. I used case statements and multiple joins for the fractional sums. Will try you this and let you know in case of any questions.

@user1708730: Note the fix: Casting would round, we need truncation there.
